# Derivation of gradient for SVM function.

Tags: matrices, vector-analysis, machine-learning

referring to the site here: http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/
Given this equation:

$L_i = \sum_{j\neq y_i} \left[ \max(0, w_j^Tx_i - w_{y_i}^Tx_i + \Delta) \right]$

TO find the gradient with respect to W which is a matrix, The text jumps to the solution as:

$\nabla_{w_{y_i}} L_i = - \left( \sum_{j\neq y_i} \mathbb{1}(w_j^Tx_i - w_{y_i}^Tx_i + \Delta > 0) \right) x_i$

and

$\nabla_{w_j} L_i = \mathbb{1}(w_j^Tx_i - w_{y_i}^Tx_i + \Delta > 0) x_i$

It's been quite a while since I've done multivariable calculus and I have no idea how they arrived at this solution. Can someone provide a detailed step by step procedure on how this was done? An example of a 2x2 matrix would help me understand how all of this was derived.

Also why does the summation disapear on the last equation? Is that a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $j \ne y_i$. The gradient of $w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta$ with respect to $w_{y_i}$ is $-x_i$. (If this is not obvious to you, you should consider the function $f(w_{y_i}) := w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta$, take all partial derivatives (with respect to the components of $w_{y_i}$, and stack them into a vector to form the gradient.)

---

Next, let's consider $g(w_{y_i}) := \max(0, w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta)$. There are a few cases:

- when $w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta > 0$, then $g(w_{y_i}) = f(w_{y_i})$ (see above) so the gradient is $-x_i$.
- when $w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta < 0$, then $g(w_{y_i})$ is zero, so the gradient is $0$.
- the site you linked is probably glossing over the non-differentiability in the case $w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta=0$, so I will ignore it.

This yields the gradient $- \mathbb{1}(w_j^\top x_i - w_{y_i}^\top x_i + \Delta > 0) x_i$.

---

Next, just sum the above over the cases $j \ne y_i$ to get the first gradient $\nabla_{w_{y_i}} L_i$.

---

---

The third expression is the gradient with respect to $w_j$ **for $j \ne y_i$**. There is only one instance of $w_j$ in the expression $L_i$, so that is why there is no sum. The reason why there is a sum when we take the gradient with respect to $w_{y_i}$ is because $w_{y_i}$ appears in every addend in the sum.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I still don't understand your explanation for why the summation disappears when the gradient is taken in respect to $w_j$. 

If $W$ was a 3x3 matrix and $w_{y_i} = w_0$, 

$L_0$ would look like this:

$L_0 = \max(0, w_1^Tx_0 - w_0^Tx_0 + 1) + \max(0, w_2^Tx_0 - w_0^Tx_0 + 1)$


That's two addends with both  $w_{y_i}$ and $w_j$. Could you elucidate?

Comment: @BrianYeh The computation you are doing here is the gradient with respect to $w_{y_i}$, which is the first gradient on that page, which has a sum and agrees with your computation having two terms. If you read the page carefully, you will see that the second gradient is with respect to $w_j$ for $j \ne y_i$, so it will not involve a sum.

Comment: Could you also show how to obtain the derivative wrt x. I have no idea how to get there - appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In response too "Also why does the summation disapear on the last equation? Is that a mistake?"

The confusion here arises from the max function... To keep things simple and lets not think about the max function and Lets say...

$Li=∑_{j≠yi}[w_j^Tx_i−w_{y_i}^Tx_i+Δ)]$

This is roughly equal to

$w_0^Tx_i + w_1^Tx_i + w_j^Tx_i$ ... + $w_{y_i}^Tx_i + w_{y_i}^Tx_i + w_{y_i}^Tx_i +$ ...

but you are taking the gradient with respect to a single row either j = 0 or j = 1 or j = 2 or .... So if you took the gradient with lets say $w_2$

$\frac{\partial{w_0^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} + \frac{\partial{w_1^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} + \frac{\partial{w_2^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} + ... + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}} ...$

All terms would go to zero except $\frac{\partial{w_2^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_2}}$ which is equal to $x_i$

For $\nabla_{w_{y_i}} L_i$ you get ...

$\frac{\partial{w_0^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_1^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_2^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + ... + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} ...$

which cancels to...

$\frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + \frac{\partial{w_{y_i}^Tx_i}}{\partial{w_{y_i}}} + ... = x_i + x_i + x_i + ...$

Hence as you can see the sum remains for $w_{y_i}$ ...